# How to apply CSS to the first iteration of a <cfloop> but not to subsequent iterations?

Tags: jquery, css, coldfusion

I have a `<cfloop>` outputting a query to a jQuery sortable list. All the sortable tags(`<h3>, <div>`, etc) are contained within the loop. I need to anchor the first `<h3>` element to a set area on the page using CSS. But I don't want to apply this CSS after the first iteration.

```
<cfloop query="createAgendaTopics">
    <h3 style="color:#FFFFFF; font-weight:bold;">
       <cfoutput>#One.categoryName#</cfoutput>
    </h3>
    <div>
         <cfoutput>#One.subCategoryGUID#</cfoutput>
    </div>        
 </cfloop>
```

Comment: Please share some code...

Comment: Sure, I've included it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you output/loop a query it has a built in currentRow attribute `QueryName.CurrentRow`

I put this into a cfoutput to simplify the code a bit.

```
<cfoutput query="createAgendaTopics">
    <cfif createAgendaTopics.CurrentRow EQ 1>
        <h3 style="color:##FFFFFF; font-weight:bold;">#One.categoryName#</h3>
    <cfelse>
        <div>#One.subCategoryGUID#</div>         
    </cfif>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Is there an option for odd/even, instead of specific integers?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<cfloop query=createAgendaTopics">
    <cfif currentrow is 1>
       code for first row
    <cfelse>
      code for remaining rows
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could simply use the `:first-child` [CSS pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-child).

Example:

```
<style type="text/css">
   .agendaTopics :first-child {
       /* css to "anchor the first element to a set area on the page" */
   }
</style>

<div class="agendaTopics">
  <cfloop query="createAgendaTopics">
     <h3 style="color:#FFFFFF; font-weight:bold;">
       <cfoutput>#One.categoryName#</cfoutput>
     </h3>
     <div>
       <cfoutput>#One.subCategoryGUID#</cfoutput>
     </div>         
   </cfloop>
 </div>
```

Although I'm not sure what you mean by

> I need to anchor the first element to a set area on the page using
>   CSS.

You should be able to apply whatever CSS styles you want to the first element using the above code.